# Dynamic calculations in a materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, data-warehouse

I have a problem  I created a materialized view which works perfectly. But now I need to perform some calculations with the data in my view . The view contains the working hours of employees who worked in different projects. Every project has a fixed amount of time (time_available) in which the employee has to finish the project. I aggregated the working hours to month for better presentation. What I want to accomplish here is a "simple" subtraction of "fixed amount for a project" minus "working hours" for the employee.
The problem here is that some project have duration of more that just one month. Naturally all my values are in one tuple for every month. So when I have 3 month of working hours for a project my view looks like this:

MV_Working_Hours:

```
Project --- Time_Available --- DATE --- Employee --- Working Days
Project A --- 50 Days --- 2011-05 --- Mr. A --- 15 Days
Project A --- 50 Days --- 2011-06 --- Mr. A --- 16 Days
Project A --- 50 Days --- 2011-07 --- Mr. A --- 16 Days
```

What I want to do is to calculate the remaining days like this :

```
Project --- Time_Available --- DATE --- Employee --- Working d in Month ---remaining days
Project A --- 50 Days --- 2011-05 --- Mr. A --- 15 Days --- 35 Days
Project A --- 50 Days --- 2011-06 --- Mr. A --- 16 Days --- 19 Days <--- I get here 34 which is for my need wrong !!!
Project A --- 50 Days --- 2011-07 --- Mr. A --- 16 Days --- 3 Days
```

Is there a way to realize this with "just" sql or do I have to use pl/sql in the OWB? I use the OWB version 11gR2

thx

Comment: Hi, I got a problem. I use the sql developer. When I run the sql-statement the my values are correct. But when I create a table with the statement or a view the values are wrong. What could be the cause of this problem? Any suggestions? THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use analytic functions to generate the running total.  Something like

```
SELECT project,
       time_available,
       date_column,
       employee,
       working_days_in_month,
       time_available - 
         sum(working_days) over (partition by project 
                                     order by date) remaining_days
  FROM mv_working_hours
```

Comment: Okay I have problem with the realization of the new view. I get wrong results when I create a view or table. When I execute the statement in the sql developer the values are correct .What could possible cause this error.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with analytic SQL functions.

11gR2 http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10810/analysis.htm

```
SUM( "Working Days" )
  OVER (PARTITION BY "Project", "Employee"
  ORDER BY "DATE" 
  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

You should be able to subtract that from `"Time_Available"` (you'll have a potential for returning negative values, replacing those with zeros can be handled in SQL as well)

---

BTW, I can't help but like your chosen title for the result... `"reaming days"`

Depending on the project, Mr. A might feel that column title is appropriate and justified.

Comment: hi, thx u for your quick answer. Your solution works perfectly! And I really enjoyed your comment on my naming :) A little typo and things chance "dramatically" :P thx again